# Where can I find FAA procedure amendments?

Tags: faa-regulations

I'm looking at the [*IFR Takeoff Minimums and (Obstacle) Departure Procedures*](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1611/SW4TO.PDF) for [Goodyear, AZ (KGYR)](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KGYR). It says:

> Takeoff Minimums and (Obstacle) Departure Procedures AMDT 1 14317
>   (FAA) Departure Procedure: Use POTER RNAV Departure

I would like to read this amendment but my Google-Fu is failing me. Help?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you're looking at them: that number is telling you that the current procedure *is* AMDT 1 14317. Have a look at the other procedures throughout the same document and you'll see they're all numbered in a similar way.

In your example, AMDT 1 14317 is Amendment 1, made on November 13, 2014. The date format is a [Julian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) or, if you prefer, YYDDD: it's the 317th day of 2014, i.e. November 13, 2014. The format is explained in the [FAA's FAQ](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/obst_data/odtfaqs/) on obstacle data (and it's mentioned [in other documents](http://www.csobeech.com/files/FAA-NACO-ChartRevision.pdf)).

If the procedure has never been amended it's marked ORIG, e.g. at Beaver Muni (U52):

> **BEAVER, UT**
>   BEAVER MUNI (U52)
>   TAKEOFF MINIMUMS AND (OBSTACLE) DEPARTURE PROCEDURES
>   ORIG 07242 (FAA)
>   TAKEOFF MINIMUMS: [...]

Comment: @mins I updated the answer