# What is this small number on the top right of an IAP?

Tags: faa, instrument-procedures, publications

I've looked in the instrument procedures handbook, and I cannot locate a reference for what this 5-digit number on the top right above the approach name is.

What is this number, and what does it mean?

[image: IAP]

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33012/62)

Comment: Would it have been that hard to write it 2019-06-20 instead? It has all the same properties (strictly monotonically increasing, same lexicographic ordering) and uses only twice the amount of space (technically, less, since the hyphens are narrower than a digit), but is much clearer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag There is also ISO ordinal date format, which would yield: 2019-171, which is a standard format, and more likely to be recognisable than what is there.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: That would indeed at least make it clear that it is a date. Still requires mental gymnastics to actually figure out how old the revision is.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Well, in some cases more, some cases less. Given two of these reports, it's trivial to determine the number of days between them.

Comment: Honest question - I don't know the answer, @JörgWMittag, does it really matter how old the revision is? If you're looking at two copies, it's very easy to determine that `18254` is older than `19171`, thus `18254` should be thrown out as no longer accurate/current. There's no guarantee that `19171` is still current (the newest release), but it's _newer_ and that's the important thing, no?

Comment: So which chart would be more recent? 2020-05-04 or 2020-04-05 ? The answer depends on your personal background not on the chart itself, and that makes it ambiguous, and that makes it dangerous. Year and day of year is simple and does not involve parsing the date string and it doesn't matter if the user can parse the date string as long as they know it is just an issue number.

Comment: @PaulSmith Except that yyyy-mm-dd isn't a personal preference, it's an ISO standard, ISO 8601. Which also contains the ordinal date (yyyy-jjj) format mentioned above. As a human factors person, the format I have always preferred -- which isn't an ISO standard -- is 2020-MAY-05. In either English or French, nearly everyone can grok it with minimal mental processing.

Comment: @grumpy1arrival - I didn't say it was preference, I said it was your background. My background, and apparently yours, is y-m-d or d-m-y, but our cousins almost always use m-d-y.  That and the fact that it requires any parsing at all is what rules it out.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is the year followed by the day of the year of the last ammendment to the **chart**. If there have been no changes to the chart since it was first issued, this space is blank. In this case the chart was revised on the 171st day of 2019. If you look at the bottom left hand portion of the chart, the date shows the last time the **procedure** was revised e.g.—17AUG17. Apparently there were changes to the chart (obstacles,  name of the airport, typos in the notes, etc.) that did not affect the procedure, so the dates are different.

Refer to the Aviation Chart User’s Guide.

> The Date of Latest Revision is shown on the top margin above the
>   procedure title. The Date of Latest Revision identifies the Julian
>   date the chart was last revised for any reason. The first two digits
>   indicate the year, the last three digits indicate the day of the year
>   (001 to 365/6).
>
> The FAA Procedure Amendment Number, located on the left bottom margin
>   below the City, State, represents the most current amendment of a
>   given procedure. The Procedure Amendment Effective Date represents the
>   AIRAC cycle date on which the procedure amendment was incorporated
>   into the chart. Updates to the amendment number and effective date
>   represent procedural/criteria revisions to the charted procedure,
>   e.g., course, fix, altitude, minima, etc.